# Sin Cos equation help

Tags: triangles

Can you please help me prove that this equation is true?
$$\left(1- \frac{2\tan(x)}{\sin(2x)}\right)^2 = \left(1- \frac{2\tan(x)}{\tan(2x)}\right)^2$$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Please edit your question to include your attempts and ask a specific question where you get stuck. There is an obvious first step you should be taking without asking us.

Comment: @user2661923 It's correct. Without squaring both sides, it is not.

Comment: Sin Cos equation but there is no Cos?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming you are familiar with half and double angle formulae(especially manipulation in terms of $\tan(\theta/2)$,
we shall be using the following formulae for the proof :-

$\sin2x = \frac{2\tan x}{1+\tan^2(x)} $
$\tan2x = \frac{2\tan x}{1-\tan^2(x)}$

Now to prove the following relation,

1. Substitute $\sin2x$ and $\tan2x$ on the LHS and RHS of the equation
2. We notice that the $2\tan x$ terms get cancelled leaving us with:
   $(1-(1+\tan^2(x))^2 = (1-(1-\tan^2(x))^2$
3. Opening the parentheses, this simplifies to:
   $(-\tan^2(x))^2 = (\tan^2(x))^2$
4. We may absorb the negative sign on the LHS, leaving us with:
   $\tan^4(x) = \tan^4(x)$

   Hence proving that the relation is true.

   Hope this helps!

Comment: Hello and Welcome to Mathematics StackExchange. You are requested not to answer low quality questions which show no effort on the asker’s part, as outlined by the recent [Enforcement of Quality Standards](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/enforcement-of-quality-standards).

Comment: You are also requested to learn the formatting method of [mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: Thanks @MrKaushik, seems like this is a good way to prove. :)